# Can jenkins the build-flow plugin trigger manual jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am currently trying to create a build pipeline. The buildflow plugin looks interesting, but I cannot find any information on whether manual steps are possible.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem this is possible yet, but you can look at the [build pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) which supports manual steps. This is an alternative plugin for implementing build pipelines that also includes nice visualizations.

Comment: Hi. I'm already using this plugin for another build, but it's getting very unwieldy for a complicated build. For example, if I have 2 jobs leading to a single job (job-1 builds job-2a, and job-2b. job2b builds job-3, job-4 builds _after_ job-2a, and job-3), the job shows twice on the build screen, but only 1 is updated (i.e. it gets built once [which is correct], but one 'job' box stays blue).

Comment: Also, the build-pipeline gets unwieldy to update a job when you add/remove steps, or need to change parameters being passed around

Comment: Yeah, I know. Hopefully the build-pipeline plugin gets support for visualizing build-flow jobs. The build-flow plugin could implement a manual step, of course, but then you would need some way to visualize it.